# Erreur 'installation de Magento à l'aide de XAMPP

Tags: magento2.3.4

Salut à tous,

Je suis nouveau ici et je viens de commencer avec Magento.

J'utilise XAMPP v3.2.4  pour installer Magento v2.3.4 en local. j'obtiens les erreurs suivantes en etape 6 d'installation:

[image]

Comment: Can you please translate the error message in English and share?

Comment: Please refer to the blog post for install Magento on windows using Xampp if it helps!
https://meetanshi.com/blog/install-magento-2-on-localhost-using-xampp/

Comment: j ai bien suivi le document mais toujours j'ai la même erreur :(

Comment: Try to install the new one with help of https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-install-magento-2-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

triggerEventUntil (Object (Closure), Object (Zend \ Mvc \ MvcEvent)) # 25 C: \ wamp64 \ www \ magento-ce-2.3.4-p2-2020-04-25-01-06-17 \ setup \ index .php (39): Zend \ Mvc \ Application-> run () # 26 {main} Next Magento \ Framework \ Setup \ Exception: Unable to apply the Magento data fix \ Theme \ Setup \ Patch \ Data \ RegisterThemes for the Magento_Theme module. Original exception message: incorrect file in C: \ wamp64 \ www \ magento-ce-2.3.4-p2-2020-04-25-01-06-17 \ vendor \ magento \ framework \ Setup \ Patch \ PatchApplier.php: 170 Stack trace: # 0 C: \ wamp64 \ www \ magento-ce-2.3.4-p2-2020-04-25-01-06-17 \ setup \ src \ Magento \ Setup \ Model \ Installer.php (1010): Magento \ Framework \ Setup \ Patch \ PatchApplier-> applyDataPatch ('Magento_Theme') # 1 C: \ wamp64 \ www \ magento-ce-2.3.4-p2-2020-04-25-01 -06-17 \ setup \ src \ Magento \ Setup \ Model \ Installer.php (879): Magento \ Setup \ Model \ Installer->